# OpenGL doesn't texture the model properly

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I have a problem with my LWJGL program, the model which I'm trying to texture looks crashed. I'm using slick to load the texture.

Stuff I'm using:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3fi9wlq9tt5cey0/AAD7JDh6-KQHLGyHZqjstG6Da?dl=0

There is my rendering code:

```
public void render(int id){
    glPushMatrix(); 
    ShaderLoader.start();

    int vertexBuffer = vboVertexBuffers.get(id);
    int textureBuffer = vboTextureBuffers.get(id);
    int textureId = textureIds.get(id);
    int normalBuffer = vboNormalBuffers.get(id);
    int facesAmount = vboFaces.get(id);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureBuffer);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBuffer);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, 128.f);
    glMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, UtilFloatBuffer.asFloatBuffer(new float[]{0.6f, 0.2f, 0.0f, 0}));

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, facesAmount);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    ShaderLoader.stop();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

and there is part of code used to load a model exported from Blender (with normals, etc)

```
try
        {
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                //parsing
                if(line.startsWith("v ")){
                    float x = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]);
                    float y = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]);
                    float z = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3]);
                    m.vertices.add(new Vector3f(x,y,z));
                }
                else if(line.startsWith("vt ")){
                    float x = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]);
                    float y = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]);
                    m.textureCoords.add(new Vector2f(x,y));
                }
                else if(line.startsWith("vn ")){
                    float x = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]);
                    float y = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]);
                    float z = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3]);
                    m.normals.add(new Vector3f(x,y,z));
                }
                else if(line.startsWith("f ")){
                    Vector3f vertexIndices = new Vector3f(
                            Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1].split("/")[0]),
                            Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2].split("/")[0]),
                            Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3].split("/")[0])
                            );
                    Vector3f textureIndices = new Vector3f(
                            Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1].split("/")[1]),
                            Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2].split("/")[1]),
                            Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3].split("/")[1])
                            );
                    Vector3f normalIndices = new Vector3f(
                            Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1].split("/")[2]),
                            Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2].split("/")[2]),
                            Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3].split("/")[2]));
                    m.faces.add(new Face(vertexIndices, textureIndices, normalIndices));
                }
```

Comment: You don't have to unbind a GL_ARRAY_BUFFER after you switch it. Really you just need it at the end of after all binds.

Comment: It is totally unclear how your geoemtry data is created. Judging from the image, my first guess is that you don't duplicate the vertices as needed. Can you post your `Face` class? Also, using floats for the indices is a very bad idea...

Comment: @derhass There is face class: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b2pu8oe9pq7r2x2/Face.java?dl=0

Comment: @KamilZielińskiL your code does not correclty deal with the OBJ format at all (from what I can see). It looks like you just render the raw arrays, not using the index data at all, and not correctly creating OpenGL vertices for each unique attribute index combination.

Comment: So how should I do it?
I'm mixing it all here: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wmbztnddc19zwcr/vbo.java?dl=0
Before texturing I didn't have any problem with model, normals and lights, everything was fine, and I'm using shaders from here: 
http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/GLSL_Tutorial:_Texturing